How to get unknown nullability function return type in Kotlin?
What I want to achieve is to get Any! return type from function, so I can determine myself whether to handle nullability or not. The only way to get this type I found is to call a Java function.
For example:
public static Integer getInt(JsonObject json, String key) {
    return json.get(key).getAsInt();
}

This way I can use it in Kotlin as either Nullable or Non-nullable type.
getInt(json, "id") ?: 0 or getInt(json, "id"). Kotlin compiler won't complain about nullability, because the return type is Int!.
Is there any approach to create return type like this in Kotlin without using Java?
P.S. I don't really want to put !! in each function call or create two functions in Kotlin like getInt(...) and getIntOrNull(...).

You cannot do this. This goes completely against the design of Kotlin. If the function can return null, use a nullable type. If it can never return null, use a non-nullable type. So, assuming your function can return null, why do you want to not handle nulls in some cases but not others?

Well, I can, as I showed the solution using Java. And as for your question, in some cases I am sure that the value won't be null.

I mean you cannot do this with only Kotlin, of course. If you are sure that the value won't be null in some cases, then you should design it so that it can return a non-nullable only in those cases. Please explain what kind of thing you are building, and in what situations the function can and cannot return null. This is an XY Problem.

Ok, here is an example:
I have a Map<String, Player> which contains players by their names. I have a function that is executed on player join the server. In that case player haven't been put in the map yet, so if we attempt to get it, we'll get null. That's the situation where I handle the nullability. Also I have another function that is executed when player presses some key. In that case player has already been put in the map and I am certain that It won't be null, so I want to get it without !!.

!! or two separate functions is the way to go. Imagine in the future you find out you assumed a non-null value in some case and it turned out to be not true. Now you would like to re-verify all places where you assumed non-nullability. How do you find these places?

If your code is structured correctly your "nullable" value will be smart-casted to non-null after null checking it once. There's probably some bad design we don't see.

Well, I'll see the NullPointerException.

Pawel, I'm getting values from Json, there is no way they're gonna be smart casted.
Like this:
private fun JsonObject.int(key: String) = Gson.fromJson(this[key], Int::class.java)

GSON does not mesh well with Kotlin in the first place. And the fact that you seem to operate on raw JsonObject instead of parsed DTO is not the greatest design either.

The reason I don’t parse the whole objects is that in some cases I need to process read value from json. For example, if the json doesn’t contain the price, i will call price calculation function from the code. It is pretty similar to writing a custom GSON deserializer. So, in my case I wouldn’t consider it a bad design.

broot’s suggestion is the best solution, IMO. Have a differently named version of the function that internally asserts non-null. It will make bug-hunting much easier.

I edited my answer to explain in more detail why you should embrace the null-safety instead of trying to circumvent it.

Just declare it as Any?. The compiler will enforce by default that you handle the nullability afterwards. when you decide to ignore the nullability later on, just apply the !! operator.

To address your reluctance to go this way: The null-safety in Kotlin is one of the major advantages over Java. Having a reference that can be invalid at runtime because it unexpectedly doesn't point to anything is a huge source for bugs. Tony Hoare even calls it his billion-dollar mistake that he popularized the null reference in the computing world: A lot of even statically typed programming languages adopted the use of such null references which was - and still is - a major cause for system failures that I am willing to bet did cost the global economy a lot more than just one bilion dollars in erroneous results, disrupted service availability and maintainance.
Now we have Kotlin as a modern main-stream programming language that incorporates nullability into its type system so you already see at compile time where you try to access a reference that might be non-existing at runtime. It even allows you an elegant way with the fallback operators ?. and ?: to handle these cases and once checked the type inference system automatically applies smart-casts so you do not have to repeat these null-checks. It even allows you to ignore all warnings and access the reference nonetheless with the !! operator (which you shouldn't by the way, which my original answer probably wasn't that clear about). It effectively eliminates an entire class of errors.
This is like a dream come true. I've seen a lot of programming languages over the last thirty years that loaded the responsibility for keeping track of the type and the nullability of a type off to the developer. Yes, a capable developer can handle that to a certain degree that may appear acceptable, but that doesn't scale well when the code base grows and since we are talking about humans, there will always be a remainder of undetected bugs. Unless you are Donald Knuth, of course. But even an extraordinarily capable developer will find that letting the compiler handle null-safety will take a lot of mental load off of them, freeing capacities that can be used elsewhere.
The evolution of programming languages is a long history of insufficiencies that were overcome bit by bit. You can see null-safety in Kotlin as a gift given to you by  generations of programmers that had to endure all the problems that are associated with unchecked nullabilities.
Don't throw this gift away so carelessly. There are very good reasons why null-safety is implemented in Kotlin as it is, even when you cannot see the benefits at first glance and feel hindered by the compiler constantly nagging you. I promise you that your use case of retrieving map values or deserializing JSON can be elegantly implemented with Kotlin's null-safety as it is intended to be used. Try to embrace this.

Yeah, forgot to mention, I also don't want to put !! in each call, because I have lots of function calls.

You might not want to, but you're going to have to.

You might be able to reduce the number of !! by pulling the value out of the map just once (with !!), assigning it to a (non-nullable) variable, and using that thereafter.  But you won't be able to (and shouldn't) avoid a null check or assertion entirely.
